# How to change specific file extensions in a folder using Python ?

Tags: python, file

I read some information about changing file extension using python code. I have giant folder with several file types like `.csv`, `.json` and `.sf1`. All I need to do is to replace all `.sf1` to `.txt` file. Any suggested code in python would help.

Comment: Wondering why your question has been favourited twice, this has been asked to the point of exhaustion. Please try a minimal amount of googling before asking a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import os

os.rename('foo.bar', 'foo.baz')